# Linear search algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

The goal of my program is to find the number entered by user in an array of integers (array was created automatically), and to show the index of this number (or numbers, if they occurs several times). It works correctly when the desired number occurs only once in array. For example, if there is an array

```
7 8 0 4 2 7 2
```

and user entered "8", the output of program will be

```
Index of the number you entered is: 2
```

But when we have array:

```
0 5 3 9 3 7 2
```

And the user entered "3", the output will be

```
Index of the number you entered is: 3
```

And I wonder how to make the program include second "3" number which has index 5. The code of program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int i, N;

int LinearSearch(int Array[], int searchValue)
{
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i]==searchValue)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int searchValue, Array[1000];

    cout<<"Size of array: ";
    cin>>N;

    cout<<"Array: ";
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        Array[i]=rand()%10;
        cout<<Array[i]<<" ";
    }

    cout<<"Search value: ";
    cin>>searchValue;

    if (LinearSearch(Array, searchValue)==1)
        cout<<"\nIndex of the number you entered is: "<<LinearSearch(Array, searchValue)+1;
    else
        cout<<"\nNothing found";
}
```

Comment: "return" disrupt the loop and exits the function.

Comment: Your code does not match the behaviour you describe.  Try the second example: your code fails to find the value.

Comment: In C++, a function can only return one value - you can't resume it again later to get more results. But with an extra parameter specifying where to start searching, you could call the function again to search from the item after the last one you found. And keep calling and calling until one of the calls fails.

Comment: @Silencer I understand this fact, but how can I fix it?

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik return [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of indexes.

Comment: @Yakk but it worked before

Comment: @kiber the code that worked was not the code you posted.  It was different.  I can read your code, and see a clear bug that makes the 2nd example uou gave print 'Nothing found'.  Always use source control, always commit milestones, always test code you post in a question so you know it does what you say it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you return from the search function as soon as the value is located:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    if (Array[i]==searchValue)
        return i; // <-- as soon as we get here, we break the loop
}
```

therefore, you will get the first position in which `searchValue` is located, which is 2 (0-based). Thus, you get 2+1 = 3. To get the last one, you will have to remove the early exit, and keep the current index in a variable, like this:

```
int LinearSearch(int Array[], int searchValue) {
    int index = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (Array[i]==searchValue) {
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways:
1. Change the LinearSearch's return value to vector, write it like this:

```
vector<int> LinearSearch(int Array[], int searchValue)
```

2.Add a vector reference variable in the parameters, it should like this:

```
int LinearSearch(int Array[], int searchValue, vector<int> &results)
```

And the the method body in LinearSearch should have little change accordingly.

Comment: How about passing in a pointer to first element and a pointer to one past the end, like a C++ programmer?  Then you can search on the tail of the array after the first find, and avoid a memory allocation.